# How long HttpConfiguration object stays in the life cycle of application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac, asp.net-web-api2

I need to use HttpConfiguration between my IOC config layer and WebApi config layer. What currently I am doing is that I have a static HttpConfiguration property in WebApi layer,

```
 public static HttpConfiguration WebApiHttpConfiguration { get; set; }
```

I am initializing this WebApiHttpConfiguration in IOC config layer,

```
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
WebApiLayer.WebApiHttpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiLayer.WebApiHttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

In Web Api Layer I have,

```
WebApiHttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
WebApiHttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    );
app.UseWebApi(WebApiHttpConfiguration);
```

Now I am fearing that how long the HttpConfiguration last?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration will not change after the server has been opened and is responding to requests.

You would have to stop the server to change the configuration.